# SQLAlchemy subquery - 'BaseQuery' object is not callable

Tags: python, html, flask, sqlalchemy

I want to create a dropdown menu (within a form) that can be used to filter customers by their status. I'm trying to create a subquery to generate the customer `id` values that match the requested status. I would then use this subquery in a main query that further filters the data.

The error I'm getting with the code below is `TypeError: 'BaseQuery' object is not callable` for this line: `status_query = appts_db.query(appts_db.id).subquery()`.

**index.html**

```html
<form action="/" method="GET">
    <select name="status">
        <option value = "All" 
            {% if status_selection == "All" %} selected {% endif %}>All</option>

        <option value = "Scheduled"
            {% if status_selection == "Scheduled" %} selected {% endif %}>Scheduled</option>

        <option value = "Completed" 
            {% if status_selection == "Completed" %} selected {% endif %}>Completed</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**models.py**

```py
class appts_db(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    customer = db.Column(db.String(100))
    status = db.Column(db.String(30))
    pickup_date = db.Column(db.String(10))
```

**views.py**

```py
@views.route('/')
def index():
    status_selection = request.args.get('status')

    # Subquery:
    if status_selection == 'All':
        status_query = appts_db.query(appts_db.id).subquery()
    elif status_selection == 'Scheduled':
        status_query = appts_db.query.filter(appts_db.status == 'Scheduled').subquery()
    elif status_selection == 'Completed':
        status_query = appts_db.query.filter(appts_db.status == 'Completed').subquery()

    # Main query:
    appts = appts_db.query.join(status_query, appts_db.id == status_query.id) \
        .order_by(appts_db.pickup_date).all()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that I just needed to use `db.session` at the beginning of my query statements:

```py
from flask import session

@views.route('/')
def index():
    status_selection = request.args.get('status')
    
    # Subquery:
    if status_selection == 'All':
        status_query = db.session.query(appts_db.id).subquery()
    elif status_selection == 'Scheduled':
        status_query = db.session.query(appts_db.id) \
            .filter(appts_db.status == 'Scheduled').subquery()
    elif status_selection == 'Completed':
        status_query = db.session.query(appts_db.id) \
            .filter(appts_db.status == 'Completed').subquery()
    else:
        status_query = db.session.query(appts_db.id).subquery()

    #Main query:
    appts = db.session.query(appts_db) \
        .filter(appts_db.id.in_(status_query)) \
        .order_by(appts_db.pickup_date).all()
```